# Is there a wrapper component for the jQuery dataTable library in ReactJS?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, datatables

I am trying to convert a project which has just HTML and JS to ReactJS. I am stuck with data table which is 'Modal responsive table' from the theme (http://foxythemes.net/preview/products/beagle/tables-datatables.html)
which is using DataTable jquery library. Is it possible to use the same in any ways with ReactJS. Any tips would help. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Jquery data table directly in React. Jquery changes dom outside the React scope. Changing the browser DOM outside your React app means React is potentially no longer handling state, events and UI rendering. You can try using this Sample React data table component code from https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/tables/datatables/

```
import React from 'react';
import { MDBDataTable } from 'mdbreact';

const DatatablePage = () => {
  const data = {
    columns: [
      {
        label: 'Name',
        field: 'name',
        sort: 'asc',
        width: 150
      },
      {
        label: 'Position',
        field: 'position',
        sort: 'asc',
        width: 270
      },
      {
        label: 'Office',
        field: 'office',
        sort: 'asc',
        width: 200
      },
      {
        label: 'Age',
        field: 'age',
        sort: 'asc',
        width: 100
      },
      {
        label: 'Start date',
        field: 'date',
        sort: 'asc',
        width: 150
      },
      {
        label: 'Salary',
        field: 'salary',
        sort: 'asc',
        width: 100
      }
    ],
    rows: [
      {
        name: 'Tiger Nixon',
        position: 'System Architect',
        office: 'Edinburgh',
        age: '61',
        date: '2011/04/25',
        salary: '$320'
      },
      {
        name: 'Garrett Winters',
        position: 'Accountant',
        office: 'Tokyo',
        age: '63',
        date: '2011/07/25',
        salary: '$170'
      },
      {
        name: 'Ashton Cox',
        position: 'Junior Technical Author',
        office: 'San Francisco',
        age: '66',
        date: '2009/01/12',
        salary: '$86'
      },
      {
        name: 'Cedric Kelly',
        position: 'Senior Javascript Developer',
        office: 'Edinburgh',
        age: '22',
        date: '2012/03/29',
        salary: '$433'
      },
      {
        name: 'Airi Satou',
        position: 'Accountant',
        office: 'Tokyo',
        age: '33',
        date: '2008/11/28',
        salary: '$162'
      },
      {
        name: 'Brielle Williamson',
        position: 'Integration Specialist',
        office: 'New York',
        age: '61',
        date: '2012/12/02',
        salary: '$372'
      },
      {
        name: 'Herrod Chandler',
        position: 'Sales Assistant',
        office: 'San Francisco',
        age: '59',
        date: '2012/08/06',
        salary: '$137'
      },
      {
        name: 'Rhona Davidson',
        position: 'Integration Specialist',
        office: 'Tokyo',
        age: '55',
        date: '2010/10/14',
        salary: '$327'
      },
      {
        name: 'Colleen Hurst',
        position: 'Javascript Developer',
        office: 'San Francisco',
        age: '39',
        date: '2009/09/15',
        salary: '$205'
      },
      {
        name: 'Sonya Frost',
        position: 'Software Engineer',
        office: 'Edinburgh',
        age: '23',
        date: '2008/12/13',
        salary: '$103'
      },
      {
        name: 'Jena Gaines',
        position: 'Office Manager',
        office: 'London',
        age: '30',
        date: '2008/12/19',
        salary: '$90'
      },
      {
        name: 'Quinn Flynn',
        position: 'Support Lead',
        office: 'Edinburgh',
        age: '22',
        date: '2013/03/03',
        salary: '$342'
      },
      {
        name: 'Charde Marshall',
        position: 'Regional Director',
        office: 'San Francisco',
        age: '36',
        date: '2008/10/16',
        salary: '$470'
      },
      {
        name: 'Haley Kennedy',
        position: 'Senior Marketing Designer',
        office: 'London',
        age: '43',
        date: '2012/12/18',
        salary: '$313'
      },
      {
        name: 'Tatyana Fitzpatrick',
        position: 'Regional Director',
        office: 'London',
        age: '19',
        date: '2010/03/17',
        salary: '$385'
      },
      {
        name: 'Michael Silva',
        position: 'Marketing Designer',
        office: 'London',
        age: '66',
        date: '2012/11/27',
        salary: '$198'
      },
      {
        name: 'Paul Byrd',
        position: 'Chief Financial Officer (CFO)',
        office: 'New York',
        age: '64',
        date: '2010/06/09',
        salary: '$725'
      },
      {
        name: 'Gloria Little',
        position: 'Systems Administrator',
        office: 'New York',
        age: '59',
        date: '2009/04/10',
        salary: '$237'
      },
      {
        name: 'Bradley Greer',
        position: 'Software Engineer',
        office: 'London',
        age: '41',
        date: '2012/10/13',
        salary: '$132'
      },
      {
        name: 'Dai Rios',
        position: 'Personnel Lead',
        office: 'Edinburgh',
        age: '35',
        date: '2012/09/26',
        salary: '$217'
      },
      {
        name: 'Jenette Caldwell',
        position: 'Development Lead',
        office: 'New York',
        age: '30',
        date: '2011/09/03',
        salary: '$345'
      },
      {
        name: 'Yuri Berry',
        position: 'Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)',
        office: 'New York',
        age: '40',
        date: '2009/06/25',
        salary: '$675'
      },
      {
        name: 'Caesar Vance',
        position: 'Pre-Sales Support',
        office: 'New York',
        age: '21',
        date: '2011/12/12',
        salary: '$106'
      },
      {
        name: 'Doris Wilder',
        position: 'Sales Assistant',
        office: 'Sidney',
        age: '23',
        date: '2010/09/20',
        salary: '$85'
      },
      {
        name: 'Angelica Ramos',
        position: 'Chief Executive Officer (CEO)',
        office: 'London',
        age: '47',
        date: '2009/10/09',
        salary: '$1'
      },
      {
        name: 'Gavin Joyce',
        position: 'Developer',
        office: 'Edinburgh',
        age: '42',
        date: '2010/12/22',
        salary: '$92'
      },
      {
        name: 'Jennifer Chang',
        position: 'Regional Director',
        office: 'Singapore',
        age: '28',
        date: '2010/11/14',
        salary: '$357'
      },
      {
        name: 'Brenden Wagner',
        position: 'Software Engineer',
        office: 'San Francisco',
        age: '28',
        date: '2011/06/07',
        salary: '$206'
      },
      {
        name: 'Fiona Green',
        position: 'Chief Operating Officer (COO)',
        office: 'San Francisco',
        age: '48',
        date: '2010/03/11',
        salary: '$850'
      },
      {
        name: 'Shou Itou',
        position: 'Regional Marketing',
        office: 'Tokyo',
        age: '20',
        date: '2011/08/14',
        salary: '$163'
      },
      {
        name: 'Michelle House',
        position: 'Integration Specialist',
        office: 'Sidney',
        age: '37',
        date: '2011/06/02',
        salary: '$95'
      },
      {
        name: 'Suki Burks',
        position: 'Developer',
        office: 'London',
        age: '53',
        date: '2009/10/22',
        salary: '$114'
      },
      {
        name: 'Prescott Bartlett',
        position: 'Technical Author',
        office: 'London',
        age: '27',
        date: '2011/05/07',
        salary: '$145'
      },
      {
        name: 'Gavin Cortez',
        position: 'Team Leader',
        office: 'San Francisco',
        age: '22',
        date: '2008/10/26',
        salary: '$235'
      },
      {
        name: 'Martena Mccray',
        position: 'Post-Sales support',
        office: 'Edinburgh',
        age: '46',
        date: '2011/03/09',
        salary: '$324'
      },
      {
        name: 'Unity Butler',
        position: 'Marketing Designer',
        office: 'San Francisco',
        age: '47',
        date: '2009/12/09',
        salary: '$85'
      },
      {
        name: 'Howard Hatfield',
        position: 'Office Manager',
        office: 'San Francisco',
        age: '51',
        date: '2008/12/16',
        salary: '$164'
      },
      {
        name: 'Hope Fuentes',
        position: 'Secretary',
        office: 'San Francisco',
        age: '41',
        date: '2010/02/12',
        salary: '$109'
      },
      {
        name: 'Vivian Harrell',
        position: 'Financial Controller',
        office: 'San Francisco',
        age: '62',
        date: '2009/02/14',
        salary: '$452'
      },
      {
        name: 'Timothy Mooney',
        position: 'Office Manager',
        office: 'London',
        age: '37',
        date: '2008/12/11',
        salary: '$136'
      },
      {
        name: 'Jackson Bradshaw',
        position: 'Director',
        office: 'New York',
        age: '65',
        date: '2008/09/26',
        salary: '$645'
      },
      {
        name: 'Olivia Liang',
        position: 'Support Engineer',
        office: 'Singapore',
        age: '64',
        date: '2011/02/03',
        salary: '$234'
      },
      {
        name: 'Bruno Nash',
        position: 'Software Engineer',
        office: 'London',
        age: '38',
        date: '2011/05/03',
        salary: '$163'
      },
      {
        name: 'Sakura Yamamoto',
        position: 'Support Engineer',
        office: 'Tokyo',
        age: '37',
        date: '2009/08/19',
        salary: '$139'
      },
      {
        name: 'Thor Walton',
        position: 'Developer',
        office: 'New York',
        age: '61',
        date: '2013/08/11',
        salary: '$98'
      },
      {
        name: 'Finn Camacho',
        position: 'Support Engineer',
        office: 'San Francisco',
        age: '47',
        date: '2009/07/07',
        salary: '$87'
      },
      {
        name: 'Serge Baldwin',
        position: 'Data Coordinator',
        office: 'Singapore',
        age: '64',
        date: '2012/04/09',
        salary: '$138'
      },
      {
        name: 'Zenaida Frank',
        position: 'Software Engineer',
        office: 'New York',
        age: '63',
        date: '2010/01/04',
        salary: '$125'
      },
      {
        name: 'Zorita Serrano',
        position: 'Software Engineer',
        office: 'San Francisco',
        age: '56',
        date: '2012/06/01',
        salary: '$115'
      },
      {
        name: 'Jennifer Acosta',
        position: 'Junior Javascript Developer',
        office: 'Edinburgh',
        age: '43',
        date: '2013/02/01',
        salary: '$75'
      },
      {
        name: 'Cara Stevens',
        position: 'Sales Assistant',
        office: 'New York',
        age: '46',
        date: '2011/12/06',
        salary: '$145'
      },
      {
        name: 'Hermione Butler',
        position: 'Regional Director',
        office: 'London',
        age: '47',
        date: '2011/03/21',
        salary: '$356'
      },
      {
        name: 'Lael Greer',
        position: 'Systems Administrator',
        office: 'London',
        age: '21',
        date: '2009/02/27',
        salary: '$103'
      },
      {
        name: 'Jonas Alexander',
        position: 'Developer',
        office: 'San Francisco',
        age: '30',
        date: '2010/07/14',
        salary: '$86'
      },
      {
        name: 'Shad Decker',
        position: 'Regional Director',
        office: 'Edinburgh',
        age: '51',
        date: '2008/11/13',
        salary: '$183'
      },
      {
        name: 'Michael Bruce',
        position: 'Javascript Developer',
        office: 'Singapore',
        age: '29',
        date: '2011/06/27',
        salary: '$183'
      },
      {
        name: 'Donna Snider',
        position: 'Customer Support',
        office: 'New York',
        age: '27',
        date: '2011/01/25',
        salary: '$112'
      }
    ]
  };

  return (
    <MDBDataTable
      striped
      bordered
      hover
      data={data}
    />
  );
}

export default DatatablePage
```

Table with Icons :

```
import React from 'react';
import { MDBTable, MDBTableBody, MDBTableHead  } from 'mdbreact';

const TablePage = (props) => {
  const data_icons = {
    columns: [
      {
        'label': '#',
        'field': 'id',
        'sort': 'asc'
      },
      {
        'label': [<i key="Lorem" className="fa fa-leaf mr-2 blue-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>, 'Lorem'],
        'field': 'lorem',
        'sort': 'asc'
      },
      {
        'label': [<i key="Ipsum" className="fa fa-leaf mr-2 teal-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>, 'Ipsum'],
        'field': 'ipsum',
        'sort': 'asc'
      },
      {
        'label': [<i key="Dolor" className="fa fa-leaf mr-2 indigo-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>, 'Dolor'],
        'field': 'dolor',
        'sort': 'asc'
      }
    ],
    rows: [
      {
        'id': 1,
        'lorem': [<i key="cell1" className="far fa-gem mr-2 grey-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>, 'Cell1'],
        'ipsum': [<i key="cell2" className="fa fa-download mr-2 grey-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>, 'Cell2'],
        'dolor': [<i key="cell3" className="fa fa-book mr-2 grey-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>, 'Cell3']
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        'lorem': [<i key="cell1" className="fa fa-graduation-cap mr-2 grey-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>, 'Cell1'],
        'ipsum': [<i key="cell2" className="fa fa-gift mr-2 grey-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>, 'Cell2'],
        'dolor': [<i key="cell3" className="far fa-image mr-2 grey-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>, 'Cell3']
      },
      {
        'id': 3,
        'lorem': [<i key="cell1" className="fa fa-magic mr-2 grey-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>, 'Cell1'],
        'ipsum': [<i key="cell2" className="fa fa-table mr-2 grey-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>, 'Cell2'],
        'dolor': [<i key="cell3" className="fa fa-edit mr-2 grey-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>, 'Cell3']
      }
    ]
  };

  return(
    <MDBTable btn fixed>
      <MDBTableHead columns={data_icons.columns} />
      <MDBTableBody rows={data_icons.rows} />
    </MDBTable>
  );
};

export default TablePage;
```

Please refer this for above code snippet: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/tables/additional/

You can also check this: http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/example.html

Comment: This looks good. the only thing is I am not able to find the responsive feature as it is in the current table. I need a + icon when its in small screen and need to show the data of the column in a popup when clicked. (Attaching the screen shot in the question)

Comment: You can  see this https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/tables/responsive/

Comment: for `+` Icon you can use https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/plus-square